# Android Library Project Export

Tags: android, android-module

I am developing first time Android Library Project that have external dependences of different libraries like retrofit and ormlite-android. The problem i am facing right now is when i use my Android Library Project .aar file inside other project the class not found exception occur when run the code. Please can any one guide me how to fix such issues. Do i have to add external libraries reference inside my dependent app ?

Comment: test it! 
But if you can it s better to add Library Project as Module to your project. 
so all external dependencies will add too

Comment: Sorry ! i cannot understand your comment